# Why does printing values from SQL table have lots of spaces in the list?

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I have a database in SQL and every time when I try to print out the values from SQL I get this output with lots of spaces.

```
<class 'list'>
('6                                                                                                   ', '6
                             ')
```

Where I expect it to be something like this

```
<class 'list'>
('6', '6')
```

Is there anything that can be done to change it?
here is what my SQL looks like

[image: SQL table]

[image: Pyhton result]

Comment: You might `strip()` the items in the list. Perhaps with a list comprehension.

Comment: It’s just a list

Comment: How are you generating the `list`? Add as update to your question.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ['6   ', '6      ']  

my_list = [x.strip(' ') for x in my_list]

print(my_list)
```